# Why can't I make an http request to the ASP.NET development server on localhost?

Tags: asp.net, loopback, asp.net-development-serv

I have an ASP.NET project (VS2008 on Windows 7 with either webforms, MVC1, or MVC2 -- all the same result for me) which is just the File->New hello world web project.  It's using the default ASP.NET development server, and when I start the server with F5, the browser never connects and I get a timeout.  I tried to debug this by telnetting to the development server's port while it was running, and I got the same result:

```
C:\Users\farmercs>telnet localhost 54752
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 54752:
Connect failed
```

I can see in the system tray that the server thinks it's running, and a `netstat -a -n` command shows that there is indeed an active TCP listener on that port.

This worked in the not-too-distant past, and I could work on web projects using the development server.  One thing that has changed since then was that [I installed the Microsoft Loopback Adapter](https://superuser.com/questions/117507/how-can-i-change-the-binding-order-of-network-adapters-in-windows-7) to accommodate a local development Oracle installation.  I'm not sure this is the problem, but it seems a likely culprit.

I also tried to hit the port using the server name itself (`http://mycomputername:54752`) but with the same result.

So, what could be blocking me from connecting?  And if it's the loopback, then what is a good way for me to retain my ability to connect to my development Oracle server while still being able to use the ASP.NET development server?

Comment: just curious. Same behavior for a non-mvc project?

Comment: Yes.  Webforms, too.  Even requesting a static file like a css page gives the same result.

Comment: Can you hit it if you try http://<machinename>:54752 instead of localhost?

Comment: @AaronS: Thanks for the suggestion.  I edited my question to reflect the result.  No luck.

Comment: Put your least used environment in a VM.

Comment: @mxmissile: I think that's probably a smart longer-term goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you checked your host file?

%SystemRoot%\windows\system32\drivers\etc\host

look if there is any redirection of localhost or 127.0.0.1 to somewhere else rather than your pc

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say, but this was it.  There was an entry to map localhost to 192.168.1.2.  I just changed my VS project to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, and it seems to work fine and the debugger attaches ok too.  I am reluctant to change that hosts entry, since I have lots of configured oracle stuff now that I think would get upset if localhost changed its definition.  Thanks for the help!